# How to reduce complexity of my nested if with specific conditions on python

Tags: python, if-statement

I have been trying to optimise this, but since each if has its own condition, i am not able to reduce its complexity

```
  for () in ():
      
        if ():
            if ():
               #Logical condition
               if ():
                #Logical condition
               else:
                #Logical condition
            
#another condition
                 if (): 
                  if (): 
                    if ():
                      #Logical condition
                      if index in ():
                        #Logical condition
```

Comment: Please, take a while to read [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Multiple `if` in a row should be combined with `&`. `if cond1: if cond2: if cond3` is the same as `if cond1 & cond2 & cond3:`

Answer (score 1):

[Logic operators](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp) are your friend. `and`, `or`, `xor`, etc

```py
for () in ():
    if () and ():
        #Logical condition
        if ():
            #Logical condition
            pass
        else:
            #Logical condition
            pass

#another condition
    if () and () and () and index in ():
        #Logical condition
        pass
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for Answering. While adding the next condition, there are two logical conditions I need to add... just let me know how to add the second one as well. Thanks again!

Comment: which *next condition* are you talking about? It's not exactly clear from how you describe it. That being said, if you have 2 conditions that both need to be met, you would use `if condition1 == True and condition2 == True`

Comment: I tried your method but the execution time for 1000 data has increased from 65 seconds to 72 seconds which is undesired. Do let me know the alternatives